# which MySQL function can be use to have the count of Orders and shipments with respect to Month?

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have Data which indicates month of Order date and month of Shipment date. I want to convert the records which will show, in each month, what is the count of orders and in same month what is the count of shipments

Because I am a beginner to SQL I could not try any way but this is the expected table.

I want to make this happen with Select statement. Please refer the image for the data by clicking here [Data with expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQD39.png)

Comment: Your sample may not be representative - if I understand your process the shipment date will  be null until shipped.

Answer (score 0):

Your question text is a bit unspecific but it's tagged "mysql" - so I assume this is what you use.

Something like this would work (please replace with exact column/table names):

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(order_date), 
  MONTH(order_date), 
  COUNT(order_date) AS order_count, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(order_date) = MONTH(shipment_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS shipped_count

FROM orders 
GROUP BY YEAR(order_date), MONTH(order_date)
```

Comment: Hello Siax, 

I dont want to split the date, wanna keep it one column as June-2022 only.
Also, here you did sum of the count, where month of both order and shipment date is same.

I dont want it that way, just want to have count , so I guess the way you took count of order date I will take the count or ship. date same way.

Comment: A more detailed description would definitely help to understand what you have in mind. E.g. is your question "Out of X orders how many were shipped within the same month" or "In one month, what is the total of orders and what is total of shipped orders (regardless when ordered)". Hope it's understandable, it makes a difference for the query

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a lack of additional information in your question, but maybe you would need something like this

```
SELECT Month(order_date) as Month, order_count, shipment_count 
SUM (order_count) 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY order_date;
```